# Synchronize Templates Show No file exists

Tags: templates, deployment

(EE 2.5.5) All of a sudden making changes to the template files stopped getting inhaled into the app. The changes are on the server, but they're not showing up on the rendered pages. I'm guessing that EE is no longer using the files, but rather the databased versions of the templates. This is borne out when I go to the Synchronize Templates page in the Control Panel: all the templates have "No file exists".

Is there some configuration setting that got mangled along the way? Any other magickal invocations to aid this along?

Update: "Design > Templates > Global Preferences > Basepath to Template File Directory" is set to our production server, though it should be set to our staging server path. When we try to update it, it says it accepts the change, but going back to the page shows it's still set to prod.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by setting this config value within config file (/system/expressionengine/config/config.php)

```
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = 'template/basepath';
```

Also check if "Basepath to Template File Directory" is already set within config file.

Comment: Yep. This was it. I was actually overriding the setting in the config file. Found the config key in http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html. Thx @BhashkarYadav.